# how to find the mean based on the days of week

Tags: python, pandas

The following code

```
test_df['Started'] = pd.to_datetime(test_df['Started'])
test_df['day count'] = test_df['Started'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%A'))
test_day_count = test_df['day count'].value_counts()
print(test_day_count)
```

Returns

```
Thursday     25
Friday       19
Saturday     13
```

these values are the number of tests started on the days. I would like to find the mean() test score for each day of the week.

I have tried adding the mean to the third line along with the name of the colum where grades are located in []

```
test_df['Started'] = pd.to_datetime(test_df['Started'])
test_df['day count'] = test_df['Started'].apply(lambda x:x.strftime('%A'))
test_day_count = test_df['day count'].value_counts().mean(test_df['marks'])
print(test_day_count)
```

I get the error 
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Answer (score 1):

use your `strftime('%A')` as a `groupby` parameter:

```
icma_df.marks.groupby(icma_df['Started'].dt.strftime('%A')).mean()
```

***demonstration***

```
icma_df = pd.DataFrame(dict(marks=np.random.rand(100),
                            Started=pd.date_range('2012-12-31', periods=100, freq='B')))

icma_df.marks.groupby(icma_df['Started'].dt.strftime('%A')).mean()
```

As pointed out by @root, this also works and looks nicer and probably quicker

```
icma_df.marks.groupby(icma_df['Started'].dt.weekday_name).mean()

Started
Friday       0.428581
Monday       0.443394
Thursday     0.485658
Tuesday      0.325027
Wednesday    0.506592
Name: marks, dtype: float64
```

Comment: You can also use `.dt.weekday_name` instead of `.dt.strftime('%A')`.